# console.log error "ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot read property 'log' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, npm, nestjs

i am new on Nestjs and javascript. I got an error just becauseof printing a text line by console.log()

```
const my_text ="123"
console.log(my_text)
```

[image]

Comment: try to set env to dev

Comment: i start code by: npm run start:dev, is that enough?

Comment: Run `npm run format` and try again. There are cases when a missing semicolon might cause an error. In your screenshot, you clearly don't have such case but it worst trying.

Comment: You don't have any code that redefines `console` do you?

Comment: No, i don't. How to do that? My code have many service, but i get error on this service (bookingService) only and the old api using BookingService also failed becauseof thís erro

Answer (score 1):

check your imports

import console from 'console'; - remove this line